# Python method invovation , missing parameter

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

Hi i'm trying to implement a profiling system so that as soon as the user logs in, the student is identified and pulls information from the student model and returns it to the homepage and probably every other page within the system. It will also append the student username to the end of the URL.... hopefully

I get this error:

> profile() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'

Urls.py

```
    # student urls.py
    # Import urls and patterns aswell as student views
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
    from student import views

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^$', views.profile, name='profile'))
```

Models.py

```
    # student models.py
    # Import the models db and validators
    # Also import user information for log in identification
    from django.db import models
    from django.core.validators import *
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User 

    # Specify attributes for the student database
    class student(models.Model):
    # Specify choices for years, gender and degree type
    YEARS = (
    ('1', '1st'),
    ('2', '2nd'),
    ('3', '3rd'),
    )
    GENDER = (
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    DEGREE = (
    ('IT', 'Information Technology'),
    ('CS', 'Computer Science'),
    )

    # Attributes for the student model specified here
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    student_ID = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=9, validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^[0-9]{9,9}$', message='Must be 9 unique numbers', code='nomatch')])
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=YEARS)
    degree = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=DEGREE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="profile_pictures", null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.student_ID
```

Views.py

```
    # student views.py
    # Import rendering and httpresponse
    # Also import student model
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from student.models import student
    from extra_curricular.models import extra_curricular
    from module.models import module
    from skill.models import skill
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    # Information box displayed on each page  
    def index(request, username):
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        person = student.objects.get(user=user)
        return render(request, 'student/home.html', {"person":person})

    #Profile page information
    def profile(request, username):
         user = User.objects.get(username=username)
         person = student.objects.get(user=user)
         experience = extra_curricular.objects.get(user=user)
         module = module.objects.get(user=user)
         skill = skill.objects.get(user=user)
         return render(request, 'student/profile.html', {"person":person}, {"experience":experience}, {"module":module}, {"skill":skill})
```

Home.html

```
        {% block content %}
    <div class = "StudentInfoMain">


    </div>
    <div id="Options">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/student/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/extra_curricular/add_extra_curricular/">Add Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">View User Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Checklist</a></li>
            <li><a href="/skill/add_skill/">My Skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="/alumni/Find_Alumni/">Contact Alumni</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class = "Homebanner">
        <p>{{ user.username }}</p>
        <p>{{ person.student_ID }}</p>
        <p>{{ person.first_name}}</p>
        <p>{{ person.last_name }}</p>
        <p>{{ person.year }}</p>
        <p>{{ person.degree }}</p>

    </div>
    <div id = "Homebody">
    <p>Hello {{person.first_name}</p>
    <p>Welcome to your E-Profile</p>
    <br>
    <p>This application is intended as an aid to you during your employment endeavours.</p>
    <p>It can be used during the process of building a curriculum vitae</p>
    <p>You may add information of experiences you have had during your educational career</p>
    <br>
    <p>For any further information: </p>
    <br>


    </div>


    <footer>

    </footer>
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def profile(request, username):
```

views.profile takes an extra argument along with the request which you haven't passed.

```
url(r'^$', views.profile, name='profile')
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not the best at this. Where do i pass this argument to?

Answer (score 0):

Your `profile` view requires a `username` argument but your URL structure does not define it. Change the line

```
url(r'^$', views.profile, name='profile'))
```

to something like

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<username>[\w\d]+)/$', views.profile, name='profile'))
```

The `profile` part at the beginning is added to differentiate it from your `index` URL.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. I'm getting a page not found error now and i'm sure its something to do with my appending the username to the end of the url

Comment: What is the URL you are testing with? How do you pass the username?

Comment: Url testing with:   url(r'^(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$', views.index, name='index')

Comment: Pass the url through the index view

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the relevant portion of your `home.html` ?

Comment: Done. Thanks for your help

Comment: @JamesSmith You can click the check mark to accept this as an answer if it solved your problem.